# Maximum Likelihood Estimation of iid rvs

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables, expected-value, maximum-likelihood

Let $X_1,…,X_$ be iid rv’s with pmf given by $_(_)=(1−)^{_−1}$,with $x_i \in [1,2,…], \theta \in (0,1)$ with $_[_]=\frac{1}{}$

How would I calculate the MLE of $\theta$?

Comment: Please include what have you tried.

Comment: I am thinking that if I can identify the type of distribution (Bernoulli, normal etc…) from the pmf then I would be able to calculate from there

Comment: Isn't it $\operatorname{Geometric}(\theta)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's consider the maximum likelihood function:

$L(\theta;\mathbf{x})=\theta^n\cdot{(1-\theta)^{(\sum_{i=1}^nx_i)-n}}$.

Now we derive the log-likelihood function and the score function:

$\mathcal{l}(\theta,\mathbf{x})=n\cdot{log(\theta)}+(\sum_{i=1}^nx_i-n)\cdot{log(1-\theta)}$,

$\mathcal{l}'(\theta,\mathbf{x})={n\over{\theta}}+{(n-\sum_{i=1}^nx_i)\over{1-\theta}}$.

Solving $\mathcal{l}'(\theta,\mathbf{x})>0$ you find that the MLE is given by:

$\hat\theta(\mathbf{x})={n\over{\sum_{i=1}^n}x_i}$

Comment: Please do not answer very poor questions. Rather, suggest, in comments below the question, ways the asker can improve the post.